# Why isn't User Timing data showing up in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to add User Timings data to an existing site that already has Google Analytics running. It seems to be correctly submitted, but **it doesn't show up in the Google Analytics dashboard.** I don't know how to debug it further... I'm stuck!

See the following HTML sample. In this example, I'm attempting to submit an 'event' and a 'timing'.
Result: The event works! But the timing doesn't appear in Google Analytics.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function universalAnalyticsPush() {
        if (!window.ga) {
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            window.ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-xx', 'auto');
        }

        window.ga.apply(window.ga, arguments);
    }

    universalAnalyticsPush('send', {
        'hitType': 'event',
        'eventCategory': 'test-corey-blobby-event',
        'eventAction': 'test-corey-marks',
        'eventLabel': 'geronimo',
        'eventValue': 33,
    });

    universalAnalyticsPush('send', {
    'hitType': 'timing',
    'timingCategory': 'test-corey-submission',
    'timingVar': 'test-corey-variation',
    'timingValue': 172,
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Something.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Looking at Google Tag Assistant, both the event and timing seem to be fine:

[image: event data is submitting]
[image: timing data is submitting]

Now, if we look in Google Analytics at Reports -> Real Time -> Events, the Event appears, and looks great:

[image: Google Analytics view of Real Time Events]

**But there's no User Timing data** (or I'm not looking in the right place for it):

[image: Google Analytics view of User Timings]

There doesn't seem to be any errors in my javascript. The only warning I'm getting is from using Google Analytics Debugger:

[image: View of the Console with 1 warning, no errors]

and Chrome's network view indicates that the tracking calls are successfully happening:

[image: Chrome got 200 OK on both the event and the timing submissions]

so.... why is Google Analytics ignoring my timing data??

Answer (score 2):

You're using the real-time event report which will show current data, but the User Timings report is not available in real-time. You'll need to wait for the data to become available (4-6 hours) and check back then. The report you're viewing for User Timings is correct.

In the meantime, I'd probably read about the [sampling rate for User Timings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings). I doubt it is affecting your data, but it is something to consider either modifying or just understanding in general.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've waited 48 hours so far; no data appears :(

Comment: @CoreyKnight did you have any luck getting the data to appear?